# how can I access to the chronos api?

Tags: mesos, mesos-chronos

I have a mesos and chronos environment, I want to use chronos api to monitor jobs status, But ...

```
curl -L http://localhost:8080/leader

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /leader. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
<hr /><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

It return 404 to me,Can anybody has ideas?
The other features work fine.
[image: web ui job status]
The API URL is : [chronos REST API DOC](https://mesos.github.io/chronos/docs/api.html)

Comment: Can you access the chronos UI/ are you certain it is installed correctly?

Comment: yes,I have installed it according official document,and it works fine,this puzzles me.

Comment: What version do you have? Leader endpoint was introduced in [3.0.0](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/releases/tag/v3.0.0) by [#741](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/pull/741)

Comment: I hava two mesos+chronos cluster, the chronos version are 2.4 and 3.0.3,both of them return 404 to me

Comment: @janisz,Thanks, Look like you are right,I found the doc in chronos packages,and it has difference url,I test on chronos 2.4 cluster,the following is result:<br/>curl -L -X GET chronos-node:8080/v1/scheduler/jobs   return 404<br/>curl -L -X GET chronos-node:8080/scheduler/jobs   return correct result

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure you are connecting to the correct host on your cluster.  It's likely chronos is not accessible via localhost or chronos-node given you are not receiving a response.

To determine where chronos is running, leverage [mesos dns](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/networking/DNS/#srv-records).

If your service is installed as `chronos`, look up the SRV record for all TCP endpoints as follows:

```
/# dig _chronos._tcp.marathon.mesos SRV

; <<>> DiG 9.12.1-P2 <<>> _chronos._tcp.marathon.mesos SRV
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39584
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_chronos._tcp.marathon.mesos.  IN      SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_chronos._tcp.marathon.mesos. 60 IN     SRV     0 0 9669 chronos-jjmux-s11.marathon.mesos.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
chronos-jjmux-s11.marathon.mesos. 60 IN A       10.0.2.15

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 198.51.100.1#53(198.51.100.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 02 22:48:02 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 114
```

In this case above, I installed via the DC/OS universe, which automatically deploys with any available port via the host network driver, however I see there is a tcp listener on port 9669 via the DNS query.  From there you can receive a response via `curl -L -X GET http://chronos.marathon.mesos:9669/scheduler/jobs`.  (note:, the chronos documentation states to prefix with `/v1`, however in some deployments, that will not be the case).

Lastly, you'll likely not want to perform a lookup of an SRV record every time.  If you installed via the DC/OS universe, chronos is deployed via marathon, however the universe package hides all the configuration options necessary to define a VIP via the DC/OS interface.  This can be addressed by manually going to the original marathon interface, where you'll be able to change the configuration (or via the marathon api).